# Docker push really slow despite high ISP upload limit

Tags: docker-push

I'm on Apple M2 Pro dev machine and I'm getting very slow docker push speeds to both Azure and Amazon Container Registries.

I'm getting 32 mbps uploads whereas my ISP offers 200 mbps on average. So ISP's network bandwidth doesn't seem to be the issue. I tried to play around with docker desktop settings but it doesn't help:  [image: Docker Desktop settings]

What are the the things I should look into to diagnose this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!